# Selenium WebDriverJS - Testing Chrome Extension Installation

Tags: google-chrome-extension, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hello all the selenium experts out there!

Using **WebDriverJS** and **ChromeDriver**, I am currently building an automated tests for extension installation process on chrome, but I cannot click the button inside **Chrome Extension Installation Popup**, which looks like this:
[image: Chrome Extension Installation Popup]

(I am not related to Right Inbox. This is just an image I found on Google)

I tried the following, but it did not work since it is not an alert box:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Is there a way to click that red-circled Add button in the image above?

Comment: Sure, if you visit http://www.rightinbox.com/install-for-chrome, and click `Add to Chrome`, you will get this dialog. It is a Chrome Dialog for installing extensions.

Comment: It seems like, this is not possible using selenium alone...

Comment: Have you looked into using desktop automation tools?

Comment: @Seanny123 Thanks for your comment. I have used AutoHotKey and Sikuli's and other macro programs before, but not in this project. I just wanted to know if it is possible to do it using Selenium, but it doesn't seem possibe...

Comment: Have you tried using [pyatom](https://github.com/pyatom/pyatom)? I had the same problem but for Ubuntu. I [solved it using ldtp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897773/how-to-accept-the-popup-presented-when-installing-extension-in-selenium)

Comment: See https://github.com/Rob--W/testing-chrome.webstore.install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring, I am convinced that this is not possible in Selenium 2.0

Comment: You can use Selenium 2.0 for testing Chrome extension. The similar problem I got during writing tests. Check this article http://releasematic.wordpress.com/2013/12/29/automation-testing-chrome-extensions/ Hope it helps.

Comment: @Bob No, it doesn't: this question is about confirming an inline install, not interacting with the extension itself.

Comment: Did you try to load unpacked extension from chrome://extensions/ ?