# Selenium ChromeDriver, cannot start Google Chrome with Extension loaded

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on creating automated tests for my Google Chrome Extension using Selenium 2.0 with:

1. [WebdriverJS](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) + NodeJS
2. [ChromeDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)
3. MacOSX 10.8.4

First, I wanted to test the installation process as well, but it doesn't seem possible to click the "Add" button when the installation dialog pops up using Selenium. ([My other SO question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499997/selenium-webdriverjs-testing-chrome-extension-installation)).

Now, I changed my plan. Instead of installing the extension as part of the test drive, I want to start Chrome with my extension installed. But I have not been successful.

Please take a look at the code below:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var o = new chrome.Options();
o.addExtensions(['extensions/chrome/chrome_extension.zip']); // crx file is just a zip file
var s = new chrome.ServiceBuilder('bin/chromedriver').build();
var driver = chrome.createDriver(o, s)
```

When I run the code above, I get the following error:
[image]

I've noticed that ChromeDriver loads a Chrome Extension called "Chrome Automation Extension 1" when it opens Chrome, so there must be a way to load another extension, either load it straight from the Webstore with the app ID, or load from local machine - packed or unpacked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the title have to do with the issue? There is nothing about "class" or "instance" here, much less what is contained in the title. But no: a class is *not* a instance of itself; although it is an instance (i.e. classes are also objects).

Comment: @user2246674 That is a definitely incorrect title. Thanks for catching it! I'll fix this

Comment: Is manifest.json at the root of your zip file? I.e. did you not accidentally put your extension files in a subdirectory before zipping it?

Comment: @RobW I have the all files under "extension" subdirectory inside the zip file, but this is how I have been uploading my extension to the Webstore. I will try with a new zip file with out the subdirectory. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @RobW THANK YOU SO MUCH! It worked! :) Please post an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that "manifest.json" is at the root of your zip file. It's a common error to accidentally zip the extension's directory instead of the extension files.

Using [zip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip):

```
cd path/to/extension
zip -ur ../chrome_extension.zip *
```

Using [7-zip](http://7-zip.org/):

```
cd path/to/extension
7z u -tzip ../chrome-extension.zip *
```